# save ASP.NET page as PDF and iTextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to save my ASP.NET page as a PDF, but I don't want to use response.write because I don't want to return it to the client. I want to save the PDF on the SERVER SIDE.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //code below saves current ASP.NET page as PDF and returns save dialog to client on where to download PDF
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();

}
```

How do I just save the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I just save the PDF?

If you want to save the pdf to the file system, simply supply an appropriate `FileStream` to the `PdfWriter.GetInstance` call instead of your `Response.OutputStream`.

---

By the way, your line

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

results in trash in the response, the `Document pdfDoc`  doesn't wrap or otherwise contain the result PDF, it merely provides an API to add content to the pdf.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the answer was simple.  the example button click code was a literal copy/paste from the documentation. I did this:
`FileStream fio = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/pdfs/ozzy.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fio);`